# How to avoid crashing?

Tags: rendering

Whenever I try to render a file (it's a bear based on a tutorial from youtube) Blender crashes after finishing Building BVH. Is there a way to prevent that or it's helpless?

Comment: Try to increase memory cache limit in User Preferences>System

Comment: @Denis it was on maximum :/

Comment: Mind specifying a bit more about your system (CPU, memory, GPU) and scene (number of faces, memory used before rendering, render engine, using CPU or GPU)?

Comment: @TLousky I don't know the GPU, memory used before rendering, render engine, nor if it was using CPU or GPU :( memory is 1,25GB, Intel(R) Celeron(R) M CPU 450 @ 2.00 GHz, and number faces is around 15.

Comment: What is the Blender version used in tutorial and by you ? See for [the version on the splash screen](http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/help.html?highlight=version#splash-screen), or in the very top of the Blender window (called [Info Window](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/info.html#info-editor)), just in the middle. You might also want to provide link to the tutorial.

Comment: @MrZak I use 2.75 and in the tutorial he used 2.70. The video can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCghBIUZyuM

Comment: Are you able to make preview render ? (It is made with `Shift`+`Z` while in the 3D View). And what is the step of the tutorial you're after ? It seems in the end the model should have something around 100 000 polys, with hair

Comment: does it crash while packing BVH, or right after. This would mean that you have an issue with the size of your lightmap, If using one, just drop the resolution in 'world properties' and see where it works.